# Eclipse Plugin java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java-8, eclipse-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

Hello I have problem with my plugin application with Java 8.

I am getting this output:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.osgi.internal.messages.Msg
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:249)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain.basicRun(WebStartMain.java:79)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain.main(WebStartMain.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Required OSGI plugin is attached. I see this class in package but My application can't see It in runtime. I have tried to manipulate with MANIFEST of my project but without success. Do You have any ideas What could be the reason of this error?

Probably important info is that Application is launching via Eclipse Neon 3 but when I am trying to run It via commandline javaws It fails.

Comment: Seeing "Could not initialize class ..." I dare say that there should be a "caused by" stanza which would give the real cause. Note that `Msg` has a static initializer which apparently threw an exception - but which?

Comment: Hello Stephan, 
Unfortunately there is no Caused by in my log files. I have checked Java logs and traces in AppData/Local/Sun and in .eclipse folder. Do You have idea about another place which should be checked?

Comment: This problem can be related with :


Exception in thread "Equinox Shutdown Hook" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "osgi.locking" "read")

Which is appearing from time to time. I have:
        <property name="jnlp.osgi.locking" value="none"/>

In my JNLP file but this is not helping.

Comment: Did you check `_workspace_/.metadata/.log`?